# Cannot install jupyter notebook extensions

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-contrib-nbextensions

I have already installed `Anaconda3-2021.11` on my Linux server (which has no Internet connection). I'm trying to install the Jupyter Notebook nbextensions so as to use the `Table of Contents` extension. However, I'm unable to install it using `conda install`.

The command I ran was

`conda install -c conda-forge jupyter_contrib_nbextensions-0.5.1-pyhd8ed1ab_2.tar.bz2`

However, I got the error message

```
LinkError: post-link script failed for package <unknown>::jupyter_contrib_nbextensions-0.5.1-pyhd8ed1ab_2
location of failed script: /root/anaconda3/bin/.jupyter_contrib_nbextensions-post-link.sh
==> script messages <==
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/anaconda3/bin/jupyter-contrib-nbextension", line 6, in <module>
    from jupyter_contrib_nbextensions.application import main
  File "/root/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/jupyter_contrib_nbextensions/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    import jupyter_nbextensions_configurator
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'jupyter_nbextensions_configurator'
```

I've also tried to install `jupyter_nbextensions_configurator` via

`conda install -c conda-forge jupyter_nbextensions_configurator-0.4.1-py37h89c1867_2.tar.bz2`

and I got a similar error message:

```
LinkError: post-link script failed for package <unknown>::jupyter_nbextensions_configurator-0.4.1-py37h89c1867_2
location of failed script: /root/anaconda3/bin/.jupyter_nbextensions_configurator-post-link.sh
==> script messages <==
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/anaconda3/bin/jupyter-nbextensions_configurator", line 7, in <module>
    from jupyter_nbextensions_configurator.application import main
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'jupyter_nbextensions_configurator'
```

How can I install the nbextensions?